# Error:(8) No resource identifier found for attribute 'constraints' in package 'android'

Tags: android

i am facing this error ...tried my best to sort out..but all in vain..if someone can help

below is the screenshot:

[image]

Problem is in the following lines of code

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stackoverflow.  In order for us to help you, you may need to [edit] your question to add additional information.  1) [Don't post images of code or error messages. Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812).  2) Please provide a [mcve] that lets up reproduce your problem.  3) [tag your question fully](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18878).  4) See [ask] and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for tips on how to ask questions that are likely to get answered.

Comment: @Kalamarico - My understanding is that Images of error messages should not be included even via edits.  See [Don't post images of code or error messages. Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812).

Comment: Have you added the dependency for ConstraintLayout in your build.gradle?

Comment: @dbc - Ok I'm reading it, I take note, thanks a lot for the advice

Comment: yes i did.but of no use.